# Including laravel blade template with button click

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I can not find a solution how to include blade template using button click.

For example lets say I have a main view:

```
<div id="HEREGOESMYTEMPLATES">
</div>
<div class="row"> 
    <button onclick="addTemplate()">ADD TEMPLATE</button>
</div>
```

Then script, which should include template

```
<script type="app/js">
  function addTemplate()
    {
       //Get template and include into div with id HEREGOESMYTEMPLATE
    }

</script>
```

And then the template itself (lets say partial.blade.php):

```
 <div>Include me to main blade file</div>
```

Is there any possible way by including it without creating every tag in JS and then appending to the div?

Thank you.

UPDATE.

As blade template is not supposed to do such work as it is rendered in backend, I used VueJS to this, which I believe is the best solution in this situation.

Comment: Seems like ajax work to me , call ajax and on success render blade (return json data from post controller method back to blade wtih html data you want to render).

Comment: @ViperTecPro it seems to be closest solution, however there were some problems changing HTML string to HTML data as. Also as blade templates are rendered in back end they are not supposed to be called without page refresh. Best way to achieve what I wanted is to use front-end framework like VueJS, which is supposed to do that kind of stuff